# Using awk to extract data and count

Tags: linux, unix, awk

How do I use awk on a file that looks like this:

```
abcd Z
efdg Z
aqbs F
edf  F
aasd A
```

I want to extract the number of times each letter of the alphabet occurs in the second column, so output should be:

```
Z 2
F 2
A 1
```

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. Among the many things sed is NOT for you can include counting or any other kind of arithmetic. So - why are you asking for a sed solution in addition to the awk one for what is clearly an awk application?

Comment: remove `sed` tag from tag list and from question description(no reason to combine `sed` and `awk`) to get a quick solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `sort | uniq` for this purpose as these two utils are designed specifically for this kind of task:

```
cat <<END | 
abcd Z
efdg Z
aqbs F
edf  F
aasd A
END
awk '{print $2}' | sort -r | uniq -c | awk '{printf "%s %d\n", $2, $1}'
```

Would produce exactly the desired output

```
Z 2
F 2
A 1
```

Here `awk '{print $2}'` is used to get the second column from a document with fields separated by one or more whitespace characters. If we knew the width of the columns is fixed, we could use a faster `cut` utility instead.

`sort -r | uniq -c` is doing the main algorithmic part of the task - sort the letters in reverse order and count the number of occurrences of each letter.

`awk '{printf "%s %d\n", $2, $1}'` does some reformatting of the `uniq -c` output to match the required format exactly.

**Update:** AWK has powerful array support so this can be done with awk alone:

```
cat <<END | 
abcd Z
efdg Z
aqbs F
edf  F
aasd A
END
awk '{a[$2]++} 
     END {n=asorti(a,b,"@ind_str_desc"); 
     for (k=1;k<=n;k++) {printf b[k], a[b[k]]} }'
```

We use the array `a` that is indexed with letters found in the input stream, and on each line the element indexed by the corresponding letter gets incremented.

In the `END` clause we reverse the order of indices and output the array.

Comment: Can it be done using just awk and wc and nothing else. how about just awk and grep -c

Comment: @identical123456 yes, this can be done with awk alone, I have updated the post.

Comment: The `asorti()` is doing nothing useful, it's just making the script unnecessarily gawk-specific. You're sorting the array `a` into the array `b` and then accessing the indices of `b` in random (usually hash) order courtesy of the `in` operator. There's also no reason to think any particular sort order would be desirable and if the output order is supposed to mimic the input order then that'd require a different approach of keeping track of key values as they appear in the input. There's also no reason to use printf instead of just print in that context.

Comment: @EdMorton Replaced enumeration based on `in` by an explicit iteration. This should ensure the order of letters in the output is descending. I agree this requirement is not stated in the OP.

Answer (score 4):

try: If you want the order of output same as Input_file then following may help you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[$2]++;next} A[$2]{print $2,A[$2];delete A[$2]}'   Input_file  Input_file
```

if you don't bother of order of $2 then following may help you.

```
awk '{A[$2]++} END{for(i in A){print i,A[i]}}'   Input_file
```

In first solution reading the Input_file twice and creating an array A whose index is $2 with it's incrementing value. then when second Input_file is being read then printing the $2 and it's count.
In Second solution creating an array A whose index $2 and incrementing value of it. Then in end section go through the array A and print it's index and array A's value.